# Add Column to Hive External Table Error

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, bigdata

Trying to add a column to an external table in HIVE but get the error below. This table currently has a thousand partitions registered and I want' to avoid re-creating the table and then running MSCK REPAIR which would take a very long time to complete.  Also, the table uses OpenCSVSerde format. How can I add a column

```
    hive> ALTER TABLE schema.Table123 ADD COLUMNS (Column1000 STRING);

    FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Unable to alter table. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: type expected at the position 0 of '<derived from deserializer>' but '<' is found.
```

Comment: Hive alter statements does not support SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME. You have use them separately as @Rijul mentioned.

Comment: Does not work, still get the same error. Not sure if this has something to do with the OpenCSVSerde?

Comment: **@Mukesh S** I'm able to run it with **schema** name as `ALTER TABLE \`schema\`.\`table\`..`