# Alter table in hive is not working for serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe' in Hive "Apache Hive (version 2.1.1-cdh6.3.4)"

Tags: hadoop, hive, alter-table, hive-serde

Environment:

> **Apache Hive (version 1.1.0-cdh5.14.2)**

I tried creating a table with below DDL.

`create external table test1 (v_src_code string,d_extraction_date date) partitioned by (d_mis_date date)  row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe' with serdeproperties ("field.delim"="~|") stored as textfile location '/hdfs_path/test1' tblproperties("serialization.null.format"="");`

Then I alter this table by adding one extra column as below.

```
 alter table test1 add columns(n_limit_id bigint);
```

This is working perfectly fine.

But recently our cluster got upgraded. The new environment is

> **Apache Hive (version 2.1.1-cdh6.3.4)**

The same table is created in this new environment. When I do alter table I get below error.

```
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Error: type expected at the position 0 of '<derived from deserializer>:bigint' but '<' is found. (state=08S01,code=1)
```

Comment: I see similar questions asked earlier but no solution given. Please see the links.    (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40919610/add-column-to-hive-external-table-error)
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44171086/how-do-i-add-columns-to-a-table-created-using-serde-when-creating-a-hive-table)
(https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Alter-external-hive-table-fails/td-p/184054)

Comment: Agree with the ^^ -- I think its a fallout from https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11985 that was implemented in Hive 2.0. You can't alter table's schema anymore if that schema is based on/derived from a serde. A follow-up JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-17713 should make it clear instead of throwing an obscure error.